# I just copied my svn folder, and when I merge it, it shows differences between folders when there's none. What's wrong here?

Tags: svn

My subversion is wrongly showing that my folder "x" is different from the branch to the trunk, even right after I create the branch.

I created the branch using the command:

```
svn copy mytrunk mybranch
```

commited the branch:

```
svn ci mybranch -m "creating my branch"
```

and did the merge (to make sure nothing was different):

```
svn merge <mybranch-url>
```

and when I give an `svn status`, it shows that 3 folders are modified (including the root):

```
 M      .
 M      a/b/aFolder
 M      x/y/anotherFolder
```

Note that it's saying that the folders are modified, but no file inside them is modified..

What is wrong here?

**--update:** even if I commit the "modified" folders, when I do the svn merge again say it's modified again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On merges SVN updates internal properties named `mergeinfo`. To inspect the actual properties that have changed with the merging on `a/b/aFolder` you can issue:

```
svn propget svn:mergeinfo a/b/aFolder
```